# named scope vs module in ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Please explain with example difference between named scope and module.

Comment: They aren't really connected. Perhaps it will help if you state your purpose of comparing them?

Comment: I think he is asking about difference between named space and module.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would use Named scope if you want to package multiple conditions in Rails such as:

```
named_scope :active, :conditions => ['active = ?', true]
named_scope :legal_age, :conditions => ['age > ?', 21]
```

the good advantage of named scopes is you can chain them together. for instance:

```
user.active.legal_age
```

Module is used to group similar things together. So normally if you have code that needs to be shared across you app you would define a module in your lib directory and put classes such as.

```
module MyModule
   class MyClass
     ....
   end
end
```

Module have other use cases, this is the main one from my experience.